# What are Penalized B-Splines?

Tags: regression, splines, regularization

I`m familiar with B-Splines and its concepts.I need to develop an algorithm for fitting noisy data with B-Splines. It seems that Penalized B-Splines are some special version of B-Splines which are suitable for fitting noisy data. Unfortunately i didn't find any simple and also thorough guide about this subject.

what are Penalized B-Splines formulas and is there any algorithm for computing them? Can you mention some references about this subject?

Comment: Some of your premises are mistaken. Penalized splines are not "some version of B-splines" -- you can have penalized splines that are not B-splines. Regression splines, smoothing splines and penalized splines may all be used with noisy data, whether or not they're B-splines.